# Generate rows where none exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a little stumped on how to generate rows when none exist for specified conditions. Apologies for the formatting since I don't know how to write tables in SO posts, but let's say I have data that looks like this:

```
    TimePeriodID    CityspanSiteKey Mean_Name   Mean
    2   123 Social Environment  4
    2   123 Youth with Adults   3.666666746
    2   123 Youth with Peers    3.5
    4   123 Social Environment  2.75
    4   123 Youth with Adults   2.555555582
    4   123 Youth with Peers    3.5
```

There are a few other Mean_Name values which I would like to include in every single time period ID, but just a `Mean` value of NULL, like the following:

```
TimePeriodID    CityspanSiteKey Mean_Name   Mean
2   123 Social Environment  4
2   123 Youth with Adults   3.666666746
2   123 Youth with Peers    3.5
2   123 Staff Build Relationships and Support Individual Youth  NULL
2   123 Staff Positively Guide Behavior NULL
4   123 Social Environment  2.75
4   123 Youth with Adults   2.555555582
4   123 Youth with Peers    3.5
4   123 Staff Build Relationships and Support Individual Youth  NULL
4   123 Staff Positively Guide Behavior NULL
5   123 Social Environment  2.75
5   123 Youth with Adults   2.555555582
5   123 Youth with Peers    3.5
5   123 Staff Build Relationships and Support Individual Youth  NULL
5   123 Staff Positively Guide Behavior NULL
6   123 Social Environment  NULL
6   123 Youth with Adults   NULL
6   123 Youth with Peers    NULL
6   123 Staff Build Relationships and Support Individual Youth  NULL
6   123 Staff Positively Guide Behavior NULL
```

What's the best way to go about doing this? I don't think CASEing will be of much use since these records don't exist.

Comment: What is "every single time period ID" ?

Comment: Simplycoding, Are the new Mean_Name stored anywhere in your DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a `cross join` and then `left join`.  Not all values are in your original data, so you might as well construct them:

```
select ti.timeperiod, c.CityspanSiteKey, m.mean_name, t.mean
from (values (2), (4), (5), (6)
     ) ti(timeperiod) cross join
     (values (123)
     ) c(CityspanSiteKey) cross join
     (values ('Social Environment'), ('Youth with Adults'), ('Youth with Peers'), ('Staff Build Relationships and Support Individual Youth'), ('Staff Positively Guide Behavior')
     ) m(mean_name) left join
     t
     on t.timeperiod = ti.timeperiod and
        t.CityspanSiteKey = c.CityspanSiteKey and
        t.mean_name = m.mean_name;
```

You can use subqueries or existing tables instead of the `values()` clause.